# How to connect to two VPNs at the same time?

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, network-bridge, network-bonding

At my university, I have to connect to the local VPN in order to be able to connect to the Internet, at the same time, I want to connect to another VPN. 
What should I do?

Comment: How do you connect to a VPN if you don't have a connection already?

Comment: At my university, we can just connect to local connection, but if we want to connect to the Internet, we should connect to the university's VPN at first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're a bit familiar with routing, default gateways and network cards, this is easy:

1. If your machine has an Ethernet port, use that. If not, add an additional WiFi card to the machine.
2. Connect to the Internal VPN using the first NIC.
3. Note the IP address range of the VPN
4. Connect the second NIC to the Internet VPN 
   This should now become the default gateway. if it doesn't, remove the default from the first NIC.
5. Add a route on the second NIC to the first NIC for the IP address range noted in #3

Done!

---

If the previous five steps don't make you go "Aha! Off course!"  then:

1. Don't do it!  **:P  ;-)**
2. Don't ask if it's possible with 1 NIC  **>:)**